# Oracle Virtualbox Network SPAN/Mirror Port

Tags: html, security, virtualbox, packet, mirror

Is there any way to setup a 'SPAN' or 'Mirror' port using VirtualBox so as to copy/mirror all network traffic from a particular virtual network to a promiscuous-mode adapter on a Virtual machine?
The use case is as follows - I need to teach a class on security and was figuring the easiest way for students to practise. The monitoring machine will likely have Zeek(Bro) installed and will be used to analyse packet metadata.